# Teradata row distribution in AMPS

Tags: row, teradata

I have a 8-AMP teradata DB. I have created a table EMPLOYEE with Employee_no column and created a Unique Primary Index. I will insert 1000 unique values (from 1 to 1000) into this table. 
Since there are only 8 AMPS and there are no duplicate values, question is 
how will teradata insert 1000 records on these 8 AMPS ?

When I searched the web I found that there can be there can be multiple unique values that can have same rowhash. But I'm not finding further information regarding the mechanism followed by teradata in this scenario.

Comment: Look at the behavior of HASH_BUCKET and HASH_ROW functions in the Teradata Manuals. There should also be more information about how Teradata hash distributes values across AMPs in the details about primary indexes in the Teradata Manuals.

Answer (score 2):

Like Rob mentioned above, you can use the HASH functions to see the table distribution of current or potential PI choices:

```
SELECT HASHAMP(HASHBUCKET(HASHROW(employee_no))) AS AMP_No, COUNT(*) AS Num_Rows
FROM employee
GROUP BY 1
```

This will tell you how many rows get sent to each AMP.  If you have a UPI like you said, it should be very even distribution.  You can include multiple columns in the HASHROW function if you have a multi-column PI.

As for the case of unique PI values with the same rowhash, that is possible.  To uniquely identify a row, the system uses the PI rowhash value and also a numeric "Uniqueness Value" to differentiate between rows with the same PI value.

I don't have a TD system to test, but give it a try and let me know.